# Understanding square braces in verilog

Tags: verilog

I don't understand what the square braces mean in the following Verilog code. Can someone please explain their purpose?

```
wire signed [I_width : -F_width] p_to_pipe[order : 0], x_to_pipe[order : 0];
```

Where `I_width= 5`, `F_width=5` and `order=2`

Answer (score 3):

The provided Verilog code defines two 2-dimensional arrays. Once component of the array is packed and the other is unpacked. A packed array is sometimes refereed to as a vector.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4 *Packed and unpacked arrays* states:

> ... The term *packed array* is used to refer to the dimensions declared before the data identifier name. The term *unpacked array* is used to refer to the dimensions declared after the data identifier name.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4.1 *Packed arrays* states:

> A packed array is a mechanism for subdividing a vector into subfields, which can be conveniently accessed as array elements. Consequently, a packed array is guaranteed to be represented as a contiguous set of bits. An unpacked array may or may not be so represented. A packed array differs from an unpacked array in that, when a packed array appears as a primary, it is treated as a single vector.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4.2 *Unpacked arrays* states:

> Unpacked arrays can be made of any data type. Arrays whose elements are themselves arrays are declared as multidimensional arrays (see 7.4.5). Unpacked arrays shall be declared by specifying the element address range(s) after the declared identifier.

Declared on the left of the net name is the packed range definition; `signed [I_width : -F_width]`. Since `I_width` and `F_width` are both 5, the range is `[5:-5]`, a 11-bit value. Being declared a packed, the value can be assigned as a whole, or assign a single bit, or part-select within the `[5:-5]` range. Begin declared as `signed` mean `p_to_pipe[unpacked_index]` can hold negative values using 2's complement.

Declared on the right of the net name is unpacked range definition; `[order : 0]`. With `order` equal to 2, `unpacked_index` of `p_to_pipe[unpacked_index]` can have a value of 0, 1 or 2. Any other value would be out of range.

Note that `x_to_pipe` has the sample dimensions as `p_to_pipe`. The packed portion of the array carries over to all variables defined in the line. Unpacked is speciffic to one variable name. Therefore:

```
wire signed [I_width : -F_width] p_to_pipe[order : 0], x_to_pipe[order : 0];
```

Is equivalent to:

```
wire signed [I_width : -F_width] p_to_pipe[order : 0];
wire signed [I_width : -F_width] x_to_pipe[order : 0];
```

I recommend reading all of [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4. It is intended for SystemVerilog but it is free unlike the Verilog language reference manuals from IEEE. If you must strictly use Verilog, try finding a copy of IEEE Std 1364. Arrays are defined in:

- IEEE Std 1364-2005 § 4.9 *Arrays*
- IEEE Std 1364-2001 § 3.10 *Arrays*
- IEEE Std 1364-1995 § 3.8 *Memories*